# Who's your model?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Let's say I have an application that accesses a SQL database. The database has two tables:

- Animals; and
- Recipes

I have an in-memory model of this database. There are two classes - `Animal` and `Recipe`. These are inherited from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have properties that map 1-to-1 to the field names in the database.

To create my data access layer, I have two more classes - `SqlAnimals` and `SqlReceipes`. Each class has a `Load` and a `Save` method. `Load` loops through the relevant table to create a list of objects. `Save` uses a list of objects to update a table. For example, `SqlRecipes.Load` returns `IList<Recipe>` and `SqlRecipes.Save` accepts `IList<Recipe>` as a parameter.

Finally, I have a form called `RecipesView`. This is based on a ViewModel - another class called `RecipesViewModel`. `RecipesViewModel` inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and contains a `BindingList<Recipe>` property.

Now here's where I get a little confused. In the example (above), I'm kind of assuming that the in-memory classes and the SQL classes are all considered to be the Model part of MVVM. However, am I correct in assuming that the in-memory model *could* be considered the ViewModel part?

Recently I heard that a ViewModel should only show data that will be displayed by the View. Since the in-memory model has every single field, then it's not a ViewModel?

Comment: Please tell me you've got a recipe for anteater stew or giraffe steaks in that database.

Comment: `left join animal.id on recipie.ingredientid`

Comment: More like `left join animal.id on recipe.animal_portion_id`. Giraffe steak and giant squid ring surf and turf is not out the question

Comment: Brevity is the soul of wit, otherwise I would have used a many-to-many join table :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVVM, ViewModel refers to the model that is accessed by the view. This does not include models that are part of your data layer.

Your classes (representation of objects) whose value are being retrieved or set by the view model is considered as Model. As long as you know the role of your model, you can distinguish if it is a Model or ViewModel when implementing MVVM. Also, ViewModels are usually platform dependent and models are platform independent.

Refer to [The MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

Comment: Does this mean that I may end up with multiple ViewModels that are similar (but not quite the same thing) as the Model classes?

Comment: @Camel yes, based on your design. You may create a shared ViewModel or a ViewModel per View.

Comment: Okay, so if a Recipe has a 1 to many relationship with Animals, then my RecipeViewModel would have a list of AnimalViewModels?

Comment: Yes. You have a RecipeViewModel that contains a list of AnimalViewModels